# Homebrew - How to upgrade a HEAD forumla?

Tags: homebrew, git

I installed `libimobiledevice` a few months ago with `brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice`, and tried to upgrade it today with `brew upgrade libimobiledevice` (no `--HEAD` because it's not an option for `brew(1)`), and I got this:

```
Warning: libimobiledevice HEAD-<commit-hash> already installed
# No upgrade happened
```

I checked the source code repository and the commit hash was not up-to-date.

So how do I upgrade a HEAD formula like `libimobiledevice`?

Edit: the commit hash is `333eb1a`, pointing to a commit in June 2020.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's `--fetch-HEAD` for `upgrade` command.
Try:

```
brew upgrade libimobiledevice --fetch-HEAD
```